# Why is my function not returning a anything?

Tags: vb.net, function

Can someone help me why I keep getting these warnings all the time?

I'm new and don't know my way around very well; it's an application, when you press the button, it takes a picture on my camera.

Here is my code:

```
Public Class test

    Public test_ID As String = "............"
    Public test_PASSWORD As String = ".........."
    Public test_IP As String = "http://.........."
    Public test_URL As String = test_IP & "osc/"

    Function post(osc_command As Object) As Object
        Dim url = test_URL + osc_command
        Dim request As Net.WebRequest = Net.WebRequest.Create(url)
        request.Credentials = New Net.NetworkCredential(test_ID, test_PASSWORD)
        Dim resp As Net.WebResponse = request.GetResponse()
    End Function

    Function takePicture() As Object
        Dim url = test_URL & "commands/execute"
        Dim payload = New Dictionary(Of Object, Object) From {
                {"name", "camera.takePicture"}
            }
        Dim request As Net.WebRequest = Net.WebRequest.Create(url)
        request.Credentials = New Net.NetworkCredential(test_ID, test_PASSWORD)
        Dim resp As Net.WebResponse = request.GetResponse()
    End Function

    Sub New()
        post("state")
        takePicture()
    End Sub

End Class
```

And Here is the button:

```
Private Sub cmdTakePicture_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cmdTakePicture.Click
    Dim testObject As New dder_testConnector.theta
    testObject.takePicture()
End Sub
```

Comment: Because your functions return nothing. A `Function` should `Return` something. What does the debugger tell you. Nothing?

Comment: How can return something?

Comment: [Function Statement (Visual Basic)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/function-statement#returning-from-a-function)

Comment: but which one should i return

Comment: How are we supposed to know that? What do you *want* to return?

Comment: Note that you're not actually reading the WebResponse content. You're missing `Using responseStream as Stream = resp.GetResponseStream() [...] End Using` and then read the stream content. Return that content, whatever that is. Avoid `Object` data type as the return value, return the actual type of the data you're receiving. Convert / Parse as required. -- It's quite important that you also declare the WebResponse with a `Using` statement.

Comment: Looks like you are taking the picture twice. Once is Sub New and once when you call .takePicture

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please refer to the documentation, which is quite clear.

The bare minimum signature for a (boolean, for example) VB.NET function is:

```
Function MyFunction() As Boolean
    Return True
End Function
```

You can also use the older VB6 form but that's not very common:

```
Function MyFunction() As Boolean
    MyFunction = True
    Exit Function
End Function
```

Now, please do go and review [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/function-statement).

Comment: My Function is now working. and the last question: How can i get the picture name from   ,, Dim resp As Net.WebResponse = request.GetResponse()  ,, i know i need to use resp to get some information but how?

Comment: @Tovaritch That's a different question; open a new on and post it there.

Answer (score 0):

In your `takePicture` and `post` functions, under the line `Dim resp As Net.WebResponse = request.GetResponse()` you'll need to add:

```
' Code to use the WebResponse goes here .... (See Jimi's comment for an example)

' Close the response to free resources.
resp.Close()

Return (whatever you wanted to return from the function)
```

Little beginner tip: Use a `Function` when you want to return some data to the caller; use a `Sub` when you don't need to return anything directly to the caller.

More info:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webresponse?view=net-5.0

Comment: Close does not release unmanaged resources. Dispose is needed. Use a Using block.

Comment: @Mary That came straight from the MS docs page itself. I do agree that `Using` is also good though.

Comment: Any class that exposes a .Dispose method means it should be called. Code snippets are not always complete.

Comment: @Mary Yup, agreed.